# DDD, Event Sourcing, and the shape of the Aggregate state

Tags: aggregate, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm having a hard time understanding the shape of the `state` that's derived applying that entity's events vs a projection of that entity's data.

Is an Aggregate's state ONLY used for determining whether or not a command can successfully be applied? Or should that state be usable in other ways?

An example - I have a Post entity for a standard blog post. I might have events like `postCreated`, `postPublished`, `postUnpublished`, etc. For my projections that I'll be persisting in my read tables, I need a projection for the base `posts` (which will include all posts, regardless of status, with lots of detail) as well as `published_posts` projection (which will only represent posts that are currently published with only the information necessary for rendering.

In the situation above, is my aggregate state ONLY supposed to be used to determine, for example, if a post can be published or unpublished, etc? If this is the case, is the shape of my state within the aggregate purely defined by what's required for these validations? **For example,  in my base `post` projection, I want to have a list of all users that have made a change to the post. In terms of validation for the aggregate/commands, I couldn't care less about the list of users that have made changes. Does that mean that this list should *not* be a part of my state within my aggregate?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: yes - limit the "state" in the aggregate to that data that you choose to cache in support of data change.

---

In my aggregates, I distinguish two different ideas:

- the *history* , aka the sequence of events that describes the changes in the lifetime of the aggregate
- the *cache*, aka the data values we tuck away because querying the event history every time kind of sucks.

There's not a lot of value in caching results that we are never going to use.

One of the underlying lessons of CQRS is that we don't need *aggregates* everywhere

> An AGGREGATE is a cluster of associated objects that we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes. -- Evans, 2003

If we aren't changing the data, then we can safely work directly with immutable copies of the data.

Answer (score 3):

The only essential purpose of the aggregate is to determine what events, if any, need to be applied to bring the aggregate's state in line with a command (if the aggregate can be brought so in line).  All state that's not needed for that purpose can be offloaded to a read-side, which can be thought of as a remix of the event stream (with each read-side only maintaining the state it needs).

That said, there are in practice, reasons to use the aggregate state directly, with the primary one being a desire for a stronger consistency for the aggregate: CQRS is inherently eventually consistent.  As with all questions of consistent updates, it's important to recognize that consistency isn't free and very often isn't even cheap; I tend to think of a project as having a consistency budget and I'm pretty miserly about spending it.

In your case, there's probably no reason to include the list of users changing a post in the aggregate state, unless e.g. there's something like "no single user can modify a given post more than *n* times".